# Identities satisfied by the image of the Young symmetrizer

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-combinatorics, young-tableaux, schur-functors, syzygies

Consider a partition $\lambda=(r_1,\ldots,r_k)$ of an integer $n$ and the corresponding Young diagram with rows of length $r_1,\ldots,r_k$ (hence ordered in non-increasing order). Counting the column lengths (in non-increasing order) gives the conjugate partition $\lambda'=(c_1,\ldots,c_l)$. I'm interested in their use in relation to the study of irreducible representations of $GL(V)$ for a vector space $V$.

**Background:** Let $a_\lambda \colon V^{\otimes n} \to \bigwedge^{c_1} V \otimes \cdots \otimes \bigwedge^{c_l}V$ and $s_\lambda \colon V^{\otimes n} \to S^{r_1} V \otimes \cdots \otimes S^{r_k} V$ be, respectively, the operators that anti-symmetrize over the columns of $\lambda$ and symmetrize over the rows of $\lambda$. There are two ways to associate a Young symmetrizer to $\lambda$: either $Y^a_\lambda = a_\lambda \iota^s_\lambda s_\lambda$ or $Y^s_\lambda = s_\lambda \iota^a_\lambda a_\lambda$, where $\iota^s_\lambda$ and $\iota^a_\lambda$ are the obvious inclusions in $V^{\otimes n}$. The image of either version is an irreducible representation of $GL(V)$ corresponding to $\lambda$ (in fact both give the same representation up to isomorphism). From my experience, the $Y^a_\lambda$ version is the one most commonly used.

Since $Y^a_\lambda$ is not always surjective, its image will satisfy some linear identities (it is in the kernel of some linear operators). Let me call a list of such identities *complete* if the intersection of their kernels is precisely equal to the image of $Y^a_\lambda$. (Perhaps a more sophisticated name for such a complete list of identities would be the *syzygy of $Y^a_\lambda$*.) One can look up such a complete list of identities in, for instance, in Sec.8.1 of [1]. It consists of two sets: (a) *intra-column* exchanges (exchanging two tensor indices belonging to the same column gives a minus sign; this is automatic in how I defined things) and (b) *inter-column* exchanges (pick two columns $i<j$, and a number $k\le c_j$; an *admissible swap* consists of a choice of $k$ boxes from column $i$ and an exchange of the indices from the top $k$ boxes of column $j$ with the chosen boxes from column $i$, preserving their relative order; for any such fixed $i$, $j$ and $k$, the sum over all admissible exchanges restricts to the identity on the image of $Y^a_\lambda$). Here's an illustrative example of an inter-column exchange for the partition $\lambda=(2,2,2)$, with ${\color{red}i}=1$, $j=2$ and ${\color{blue}k}=2$:
$$\newcommand{\cred}[1]{{\color{red}{#1}}}\newcommand{\cblu}[1]{{\color{blue}{#1}}}
  v_{\begin{smallmatrix} \cred{a} & \cblu{x} \\ \cred{b} & \cblu{y} \\ \cred{c} & z \end{smallmatrix}}
  = v_{\begin{smallmatrix} \cblu{x} & \cred{a} \\ \cblu{y} & \cred{b} \\ \cred{c} & z \end{smallmatrix}}
  + v_{\begin{smallmatrix} \cblu{x} & \cred{a} \\ \cred{b} & \cred{c} \\ \cblu{y} & z \end{smallmatrix}}
  + v_{\begin{smallmatrix} \cred{a} & \cred{b} \\ \cblu{x} & \cred{c} \\ \cblu{y} & z \end{smallmatrix}}
$$
where the tensor indices are arranged in a $\lambda$-tableau, which indicates how the symmetrization and antisymmetrization projections in $Y^a_\lambda$ have been done, and colors highlight the indices being exchanged.

[1] *William Fulton*, MR 1464693 [**Young tableaux**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1464693), ISBN: 0-521-56144-2; 0-521-56724-6.

**Question:**

1. What is a complete list of identities satisfied by the image of the alternative Young symmetrizer $Y^s_\lambda$? What is a reference where a concise description of this list can be found?
2. Do these identities have a commonly used name?

Comment: Good question! But the abuse of notation in your writing "$a_\lambda \colon V^{\otimes n} \to \bigwedge^{c_1} V \otimes \cdots \otimes \bigwedge^{c_l}V$ and $s_\lambda \colon V^{\otimes n} \to S^{r_1} V \otimes \cdots \otimes S^{r_k} V$" borders on madness. :)

Comment: Also, I take it that you are working in characteristic $0$ ? As elements of the group ring $\mathbb{Q}\left[S_n\right]$ of the symmetric group, $a_\lambda s_\lambda$ and $s_\lambda a_\lambda$ are left multiples of another (since they are both quasi-idempotent), and so the images of $V^{\otimes n}$ can also be mapped isomorphically into one another by certain elements of the group ring (appropriate multiples of $s_\lambda$ and $a_\lambda$, in fact). Thus, having characterized one of the images by identities, a characterization of the other follows automatically. But, of course, getting a ...

Comment: ... *nice* characterization is not easily dealt with in this way, and in positive characteristic this might not even work (are $s_\lambda a_\lambda$ and $a_\lambda s_\lambda$ still left multiples of one other in positive characteristic?).

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I'm quite happy to work not only in characteristic $0$ but even over $\mathbb{C}$. And you are right, I should have written the compositions as $Y^a_\lambda = a_\lambda \iota_s s_\lambda$ and $Y^s_\lambda = s_\lambda \iota_a a_\lambda$, where $\iota_s$ and $\iota_a$ are the natural inclusions in $V^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: I should also say that I am in fact after a "nice" explicit characterization of the identities. Intuitively, in row-symmetric form, there should be some inter-row exchange identities, that would be analogous to the inter-column exchange identities of the column-antisymmetric form. But I don't see an obvious translation. (Oh shoot! I mixed up _inter-_ and _intra-_ in the question. Will fix now.)

Comment: Now I've started getting questions and doubts about the Background. Are the indices of the boxes (i.e., $a,b,c,x,y,z$ in your example) supposed to be *any* arbitrary coordinate indices, or the entries of some fixed tableau of shape $\lambda$ ? And is this really proven in Fulton's Section 8.1? I don't see the Young symmetrizer $Y_\lambda^a$ appear explicitly in that section. Maybe he proves that the submodule of $V^{\otimes n}$ carved out by the inter- and intra-column exchange relations is one avatar of the Specht module; but this would make it merely isomorphic ...

Comment: ... to $Y_\lambda^a V^{\otimes n}$, not necessarily equal to it.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, thanks for your continuing interest in the question! I must confess that I have never gone through how these identities are justified in Fulton. However, I have worked with the inter-column identities extensively for a (somewhat simple) sub-class of diagrams (mostly of the shape $(2,1,\ldots,1)$ and $(2,2,1,\ldots,1)$), where they hold on the nose. See Appendix A of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.7212). Also, I've updated the example to show how the indices are to be arranged in a tableau, in case that wasn't clear before.

Comment: Just to correct some bullshit that I wrote in my previous comments: The two elements $a_\lambda s_\lambda$ and $s_\lambda a_\lambda$ are not left multiples of each other, even if the characteristic of the field is $0$. They generate the same two-sided ideal in characteristic $0$, and the left ideals they generate are isomorphic as $S_n$-modules in characteristic $0$ (not in characteristic $2$, if my computations for $\lambda = \left(2,1\right)$ are correct).